# Is there an xml way of hiding the navigation bar?

Tags: android, xml

To hide the navigation bar, android docs is providing the following solution:

```
   View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
   int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
   decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Is there any XML based way to do this as well? I tried the following way in the style and maninfest:

```
  <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

with

```
   <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
       <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
       <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
   </style>
```

But this does not seem to work.

Perhaps I can perform the above solution in my activity's XML?

Comment: Have you been able to hide it from XML? I am looking for the same.

Comment: for as far as I know Murat's answer did the trick

Comment: I'm sorry, you are talking about the `ActionBar`. I'm trying to hide the soft-key-bar.

Comment: No, I was talking about the navigationbar. But I realized removing such is not a good idea

Answer (score 2):

You could override the Base App theme in styles.xml with

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

and add this theme to your manifest e.g.

```
<application
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Answer (score 0):

set property of the navigation view as follows.

```
 android:visibility="gone"
```

or

```
 android:visibility="invisible"
```

invisible means you  cant not see the layout but it is there.

And Gone means the view is gone you can not access it by touch.

Comment: Where can I find the property of navigation view?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```

in xml file this is the code of navigationview

and

if you want to set visibility programmatically than use
like

```
navigationview.setvisibility(View.INVIBLE);
```

Comment: But I mean the standard navigation view, not my custom one

Comment: in every views this property is avilabe so it is not a problem with you know this view or that view.

Comment: just try to implement it